# "execute-api" endpoint doesn't work after SUCCESSFUL localstack deployment

Tags: serverless, aws-serverless, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli, localstack

I am very new to serverless deployment on Localstack. After successful deployment, the below endpoints work

1. `http://localhost:4566/restapis/1uo1f6vojm/dev/_user_request_/`
2. `http://localhost:4566/restapis/1uo1f6vojm/devvvvv/_user_request_/`
3. `http://localhost:4566/restapis/1uo1f6vojm/prod/_user_request_/`

but this FAILS.
**http://1uo1f6vojm.execute-api.localhost.localstack.cloud:4566/dev**

My **template.yml** is as follows: What am I missing ? and why is the url in (2) above working ?

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: hello-world-serverless
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Parameters:
  StageName:
    Type: String
    Default: dev
    AllowedValues:
      - dev
      - prod

Globals:
  Api:
    OpenApiVersion: 3.0.1
  Function:
    Runtime: nodejs18.x
    Architectures:
      - x86_64
    MemorySize: 128
    Timeout: 100

Resources:
  RestApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: !Ref StageName

  getAllItemsFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: src/handlers/get-all-items.getAllItemsHandler
      Description: A simple example for serverless apis
      Events:
        Api:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /
            Method: GET
            RestApiId: !Ref RestApi

Outputs:
  WebEndpoint:
    Description: !Sub "API Gateway endpoint URL for ${StageName} stage"
    Value: !Sub "https://${RestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/${StageName}/"
```

My **samconfig.toml** is as follows:

```
# More information about the configuration file can be found here:
# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-config.html
version = 0.1

[default]
[default.global.parameters]
stack_name = "hello-world-serverless"

[default.build.parameters]
cached = true
parallel = true

[default.validate.parameters]
lint = true

[default.deploy.parameters]
capabilities = "CAPABILITY_IAM"
confirm_changeset = true
resolve_s3 = true
s3_prefix = "hello-world-serverless"
region = "us-east-1"
image_repositories = []

[default.package.parameters]
resolve_s3 = true

[default.sync.parameters]
watch = true

[default.local_start_api.parameters]
warm_containers = "EAGER"

[default.local_start_lambda.parameters]
warm_containers = "EAGER"
```